# Squeak noise coming from clutch release mechanism when clutch disengaged

Tags: clutch, subaru, noise, outback

I need help diagnosing and fixing a sound coming from my 2007 Subaru Outback, 2.5L engine, 5 speed manual transmission.

It is making a rhythmic squeak/chirping sound at idle, almost sounds like a cricket, but faster.

The noise disappears completely when I put any kind of pressure on the clutch pedal - even a tiny slight pressure. This made me think that it could be something to do with the clutch release mechanism, so I tried holding (put a bit of pressure on) it and sure enough the sound went away.

Here is an image of what the part looks like:

[image: Subaru clutch release fork]

I believe the noise also happens when I am driving. Basically, any time the clutch pedal is completely disengaged (clutch disc engaged) it happens, but any kind of pressure on the clutch pedal removes the noise completely.

I've looked around the internet and I've heard the following possibilities:

- Dual mass flywheel
- Throwout bearing
- Clutch release mechanism needs cleaning and greasing

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: In the paragraph just below the image, you state, "*Basically, any time the **clutch is completely disengaged** it happens, ...*" Do you mean to say, anytime the clutch ***pedal*** is completely disengaged? In order for the clutch to be disengaged, the pedal must be down, yet above you state the noise goes away when the pedal is in this position. Can you clarify your statements?

Comment: @paulster2, oops, that's confusing. Yes I mean any time the clutch pedal is completely disengaged, I will edit my post as such.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely due to old slave cylinder causing the throw out bearing to make noise. I had a similar problem which was solved through this.